# Group to classes that have similar functionality but different attribute names

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 python classes, which functionality is the same, the difference, is the attributes have different names.

Whats is  pythonic why to make just have the functionality in one class, and change the attributes name ?

```
class ItemA(A):

    obj_name = 'itema_obj'
    t1 = 5 

    def __init__(self, itema_obj=None, itema_type=None, attrs=None):

        self.itema_type = itema_type
        super().__init__(obj=itema_obj, attrs=None)

    def get_context(self, name, value, attrs):
        context = super().get_context(name, value, attrs)
        if self.obj and self.obj.additional_itema_types and self.itema_type:
            if self.itema_type in self.obj.additional_itema_types:
                context['itema_obj'].itema = self.obj.additional_itema_types[self.itema_type]
        return context




class RunC(A):

    obj_name = 'runc_obj'
    tr = 6

    def __init__(self, runc_obj=None, runc_type=None, attrs=None):

        self.runc_type = runc_type
        super().__init__(obj=runc_obj, attrs=None)

    def get_context(self, name, value, attrs):
        context = super().get_context(name, value, attrs)
        if self.obj and self.obj.additional_runc_types and self.runc_type:
            if self.runc_type in self.obj.additional_runc_types:
                context['runc_obj'].runc = self.obj.additional_runc_types[self.runc_type]
        return context
```

Comment: Before trying to refactor this in a single class, ask yourself if this duplication is accidental or is really just duplication. What I mean by "accidental" is that ATM the implementations happens to be mostly similar, but it's mainly a coincidence and future changes will probably make them diverge. So think of what could cause changes in those classes and wether those changes will always impact them both in the same way or will make them diverge, and in the last case do not try to factor them out in a single class, since it will only be a waste of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caveat : before trying to refactor this in a single class, ask yourself if this duplication is accidental or is really just duplication. What I mean by "accidental" is that ATM the implementations happens to be mostly similar, but it's mainly a coincidence and future changes will probably make them diverge. So think of what could cause changes in those classes and wether those changes will always impact them both in the same way or will make them diverge, and in the last case do not try to factor them out in a single class, since it will only be a waste of time.

Now for a possible first refactoring pass (untested obviously):

```
class Common(A):
    obj_name = NotImplemented
    types_name = NotImplemented
    context_attname = NotImplemented # .runc or .itema

    def __init__(self, obj=None, type_=None, attrs=None):
        self.type_ = type_
        super().__init__(obj=obj, attrs=None)

    def _get_additional_context(self):
        if not self.obj:
            return None
        if not self.type_:
            return None
        additionals = getattr(self.obj, self.types_name, None)
        if not additionals:
            return None
        return additionals[self.type_]

    def get_context(self, name, value, attrs):
        context = super().get_context(name, value, attrs)
        additionals = self._get_additional_context()
        if additionals:
            setattr(context[self.obj_name], self.context_attname, additionals)
        return context


class ItemA(Common):

    obj_name = 'itema_obj'
    types_name = 'additional_itema_types'
    context_attrname = 'itema'

    t1 = 5 

class RunC(Common):

    obj_name = 'runc_obj'
    types_name = 'additional_runc_types'
    context_attrname = 'runc'

    tr = 6
```

This could be still factored further since `obj_name` and `types_name` are both built based on `context_attrname` and similar suffixes / postfixes, but I don't have enough context (ie if something else needs `obj_name` to be a class attribute) to know if it wouldn't break something.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the attribute values as arguments in the class contructor.

Comment: the attributes names are different, not only the values